# How can I log what software I use the most?

Tags: process, x11, logs, productivity

I really like using open source software and would like to help fund further development. Unfortunately, I have limited funds to do so. Being somewhat greedy, I would like to donate to the projects I use the most, but I am uncertain what those might be as many run somewhat behind the scenes.

What I would like to do is somehow log what programs I use the most but I am uncertain how. One thought I had was log the time each program spends having focus (ideally only while computer is unlocked). Logging the time a process spends actively doing something could be another metric. I'm not really sure how to track either of these.

What is the best way to track which software I use the most?

(For what it is worth, I generally use Arch Linux, but occasionally use Ubuntu, so portability would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wakoopa (http://social.wakoopa.com) and RescueTime (http://www.rescuetime.com) seems to do what you want. They both require a client to run in the background to track the software you use. Not sure about RescueTime, but Wakoopa stops tracking software after 30 seconds without input from mouse or keyboard.

Comment: Interesting sites. Both seem to be more advanced than I was originally thinking, but I it looks like they have good features. RescueTime doesn't have an official Linux client, but there is a third party one in the Arch repositories already. The Wakoopa package is flagged as out of date, so I'll probably give ResueTime a try first.

Comment: I've actually tried both for a short time. RescueTime was pretty detailed and had some nice graphs, but the unofficial client crashed after a while and I couldn't get it working again. Wakoopa works, and is simple enough. Shows how long you've been using the different kinds of software.